# Registro único com verificação de 2 campos - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-5

Tenho uma tabela com as colunas `id`, `nome`, `descricao` e `tipo`. No meu Request tenho:

`'nome' => 'required|unique:edificacoes'`

Até ai tudo bem, não consigo cadastrar nada com o mesmo nome, mas como eu faria para não poder cadastrar com o mesmo nome somente só também for do mesmo tipo?

Ex: Tenho o registro `01 | NomeTeste | Tipo1`, se eu tentar cadastrar `02 | NomeTeste | Tipo2` eu não consigo. Como posso fazer pra ele verificar o nome e tipo para bloquear apenas se os 2 forem iguais?

Criação da tabela:

```
Schema::create('edificacoes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->longText('nome');
            $table->longText('descricao')->nullable();
            $table->char('tipo', 4);
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Poderia postar a estrutura completa da tabela, por favor?

Comment: Postado, @MarcoAurélioDeleu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir do Laravel 5.0+, você pode usar **chave composta** da seguinte forma:

```
'nome'  => 'required|unique:{TABELA}{COLUNA}{EXCEÇÃO}{ID}
```

Seguindo essa [específicação da documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique), acredito que seu caso ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
'nome'  > 'required|unique:edificacoes,nome,NULL,id,tipo,$tipo'
```

Nessa regra, estamos dizendo (nessa ordem):

- campo **nome** requerido;
- campo **nome** único, para

  - tabela edificacoes
  - campo nome
  - qualquer registro (null)
  - coluna chave primária chama-se id
  - verificar se a coluna `tipo`
  - bate com o valor `$tipo`

Sugiro tentar usar assim:

```
'nome'  > 'required|unique:edificacoes,nome,NULL,id,tipo,tipo'
```

Na esperança de que o Laravel entenda que a segunda palavra `tipo` se refere à coluna `tipo`. Mas a documentação não especifica isso, ela simplesmente diz que o valor passado ali (por isso no meu exemplo anterior usei `$tipo`) será ignorado.

Se essa forma não funcionar, significa que o Laravel não tem a abilidade de identificar através do nome da coluna, fazendo com que você tenha que especificar o valor do `$tipo` manualmente.

Comment: Show! Funcionou passando o $tipo manualmente. Muito obrigado @MarcoAurélioDeleu

Comment: Uma outra alternativa é instalar uma dependência (https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator) que adiciona a abilidade de criar chaves compostas. Mas se vc não se importa em passar o `$tipo` manualmente, sugiro manter essa forma.

Comment: Blz depois vou dar uma olhada, mas nesse caso como eu já passava o $tipo mesmo pra usar em outro lugar, usar ele ali "emprestado" é bem mais rápido rs